# apt-get issue after upgrading to 12.04

Tags: apt

I have recently upgraded my cluster from 11.10 to 12.04. After the upgrade, I am having trouble running apt-get on the cluster nodes. I can ssh between the nodes (client-to-client; client-to-head; client-to-external etc.). However, sudo apt-get update produces the following errors:

```
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://www.openfoam.org maverick InRelease                                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                                                    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                                                   
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://www.openfoam.org maverick Release.gpg                                                              
  Something wicked happened resolving 'www.openfoam.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                                                  
Ign http://www.openfoam.org maverick Release                                                                  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                      
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                          
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources/DiffIndex                                        
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                                                  
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources/DiffIndex                                  
15% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com] [Connecting to www.openfoam.org]
```

On the headnode, I have in `/etc/network/iterfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1/24
```

On the client nodes, I have `/etc/network/iterfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Please advise.

On a "working" client node, I get:

```
mpiuser@crayN4-5150jo:~$ nslookup security.ubuntu.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   security.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.92.184
Name:   security.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.92.190
```

Ping results

```
mpiuser@crayN4-5150jo:~$ ping -c 3 security.ubuntu.com
PING security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.190) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.92.190: icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=94.6 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.190: icmp_req=2 ttl=49 time=105 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.190: icmp_req=3 ttl=49 time=103 ms

--- security.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 15674ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 94.643/101.462/105.847/4.887 ms
```

On a non-working client node:

```
mpiuser@crayN2-5150jo:~$ nslookup security.ubuntu.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
Server:     ::1
Address:    ::1#53

** server can't find security.ubuntu.com: SERVFAIL
```

Ping

```
mpiuser@crayN2-5150jo:~$ ping -c 3 security.ubuntu.com
ping: unknown host security.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Looks like a DNS issue. Please provide the output of the following commands: `nslookup security.ubuntu.com` and `ping -c 3 security.ubuntu.com` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved. I added the following line in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Just for reference, these are Google's root DNS servers, most any address will work: 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4, 5.5.5.5, etc.